# How to move to another view without using a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

My first view displays an image and action indicator while web-servers and database function are run in that background. I want the application to go to my tab view when the functions have been completed. How do I do this?

Here is what the views look like. 
[image: First and Second views]

What I have tried:

```
TabBarViewController *tab = [[TabBarViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:tab animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"first" sender:self];
```

Please can you help my to understand how to do this. I have spent many hours googling this problem and couldn't work out how to do it.

Thanks

EDIT: Added [Code](http://pastebin.com/ZRtPWujq)

Comment: at first time you want to do this , right?

Comment: @ParasJoshi Yes I want this to happen the first time the user loads the application and every time they start the application there after so the database can be updated if it needs to be.

Comment: ok i add one logic with UIImageView.. see my code...

Comment: if the view controller is in storyboard than you can't simply alloc init it. you have to get it with -destinationViewController of segue method or with identifier of controller which is UIStoryboard method. And also you need to override the -prepareForSegue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GCD to make this happen.

For instance in your `firstViewController` where you trigger downloading you can do:

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    [model downloadData];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
    });
});`

I assume your `downloadData` method is synchronous, if not you can use notifications in your model. Once data is retrieved you could `postNamedNotification` from `NSNotificationCenter` and in `firstViewController` you could register for notification and after receiving it you would call `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: Im using GCD at the moment to do all the database and web-services. so they run in the back ground while the activity indicator animates.

Comment: So the best way is to `postNamedNotification` in your GCD task and register for it in your `viewController`. Then from `viewController`'s method that is triggered by notification call `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: This Worked! Needed to add [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self]; inside the dispatch_async! Thanks.

Comment: That's great. You may consider calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` in main thread. e.g. `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self performSegueWithIdentifier ...`

Comment: If I call it in the main thread will my other function still run even if the the view changes? or will the view not change until they have run?

Comment: I guess your downloading code is synchronous, In such case after download is completed it will perform segue on main thread. It really doesn't matter in which thread you do next action. The reason `performSegue` call should be in main thread is because `UIView` related stuff is not fully thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are downloading data you can get a call when the downloading request gets finished
like the method below

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
```

and in this method you can very well present your `TabBarViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Declare A separate Method for that.

Call the below method when your function completes.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(gotonext:) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];

-(void)gotonext;
{
TabBarViewController *tab = [[TabBarViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:tab animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Yes ,You can modify it with your desired time.

Comment: The only problem with that is that I dont know how long it will take to run the functions. It could take 10 seconds to download everything and another time it might take 1 sec. I was just going to call the method after the other methods have finished. There problem im having is getting it to show the next view.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... What if you put

```
 TabBarViewController *tab = [[TabBarViewController alloc]init];
 [self presentViewController:tab animated:NO completion:nil];
```

In

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //stop the loader once the database stuff has finished and get rid of the text
        [[self firstLoader]stopAnimating];
        self.downloadingLabel.text = @"";

        });
```

UPDATE: If you want to do this sync

dispatch_sync(a_queue, ^{ wait_for_me(); });
And after that present your VC.

Comment: When I do this it moves to a View with a tabBar at the bottom but does not show any buttons or the tabPages

Comment: I needed to put [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self]; inside the dispatch_async! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take one splashView Image at starting, like bellow...

```
    @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
        UIImageView *splashView;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *splashView;
    @end
```

in AppDelegate.m file...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
    {
        splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:iphoneFrame];
        splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"];
        [self.window addSubview:splashView];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
                UINavigationController *navviewController1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
                navviewController1.title = @"FirstTitle";
        //        navviewController1.navigationBarHidden=YES;

        UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[yourviewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourviewController2" bundle:nil] autorelease];
                UINavigationController *navviewController2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
        //        navviewController2.navigationBarHidden=YES;
                navviewController2.title = @"SecondTitle";

        UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[yourviewController3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourviewController2" bundle:nil] autorelease];
                UINavigationController *navviewController3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
        //        navviewController3.navigationBarHidden=YES;
                navviewController3.title = @"ThirdTitle";

               //..... and so on depend on your requirement 

        self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navviewController1, navviewController2 , navviewController3 ,nil];
        [self performSelector:@selector(loadViewIphone) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];//**add this line at your all data are loading completed**
    } 
    else 
    {
        splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:ipadFrame];
        splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default_iPad"];
        [self.window addSubview:splashView];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self performSelector:@selector(loadViewIpad) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)loadViewIphone 
{
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];

    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];   

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];   
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [animation setDuration:1.0];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                  kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[self.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

i hope this help you...